# operator overloading '<<' and '>>' and a string

Tags: c++, overloading

I am attempting to overload an operator to act on the item class and having some difficulty because of the string. This will be split into a header and another file. (edit: oops, sorry.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class item
{
private:
    string itemName;
public:
    string getitemName() const;
    friend std::istream &operator >> (std::istream & instr, const item& R);
    friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream & outst, const item& P);
};

string item::getitemName() const
{
return itemName;
}


std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& instr, const item& R)
{
instr >> R.getitemName();
return instr;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& outst, const item& P)
{
outst << P.getitemName();
return outst;
}
```

Comment: If `getitemName` is a problem, showing it is kinda mandatory

Comment: You will probably have an issue on the `operator >>` which is supposed to feed the item you give in parameter (through the methode `getItemName()`). But the parameter is of type `const item &`, which is a bit strange. please show the `getiemName` function implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. the >> operator is going to mutate the `item`, so it must be passed a reference to a mutable, not const.
2. `item` has declared the streaming operator functions to be friends, so they have unfettered access to the internal state.

-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class item
{
private:
    string itemName;
public:
    friend std::istream &operator >> (std::istream & instr, item& R);
    friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream & outst, const item& P);
};

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& instr, item& R)
{
instr >> R.itemName;
return instr;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& outst, const item& P)
{
outst << P.itemName;
return outst;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `getItemName()` you are getting a value, not a reference to it.
You're doing something like

```
instr>>"hello"
```

and this does not make any sense since "hello", like the result of `getItemName()` is a `rvalue`.

You should do this:

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& instr, const item& R){
    instr >> R.itemName;
    return instr;
}
```

The method is a `friend`, so it can access your private member without problems!

For more info about `rvalues` and `lvalues` you can check [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c)

Comment: narrowed down the problem to the >> operator.

Comment: I'm not sure to have understood your comment here